# Magento plugin block insert

Tags: php, magento, block

i created module in magento, and i wanna add block in it but it not work to me.

my folder structure:

```
local/JR/CreateAdminController/etc/config.xml
local/JR/CreateAdminController/etc/adminhtml.xml
local/JR/CreateAdminController/controller/Adminhtml/CustomController.php
local/JR/CreateAdminController/block/Monblock.php
```

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <jr_createadmincontroller>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Mage_Core_Helper</class>
            </jr_createadmincontroller>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <foo_bar                                   before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml
                        </foo_bar>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <mycustomtab module="jr_createadmincontroller" translate="title">
            <title>Test</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/custom/</action>

        </mycustomtab>
 </menu>
</config>
```

CustomController.php

```
<?php

class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('test'));

        $block = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
            ->setText('<h1>Hello!</h1>');           


        $this->_addContent($block);
        $this->renderLayout();

    }

}
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\test.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
          <reference name="content">
          </reference>
      </default>
      <routeurfrontend_index_index>
           <reference name="content">
                <block type="test/monblock"  name="afficher_monbloc"
                          template="test/afficher.phtml" />
           </reference>
      </routeurfrontend_index_index>
</layout>
```

local/JR/CreateAdminController/block/Monblock.php

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
         return ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
     }
}
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\test\afficher.phtml

```
 <?php 
echo $this->methodblock();
?>
```

how can i include my block in modul??

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and made some change now its working as expected find the updated code below.

Files :

```
app\etc\modules\JR_CreateAdminController.xml
app\code\local\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\config.xml
app\code\local\JR\CreateAdminController\etc\adminhtml.xml
app\code\local\JR\CreateAdminController\controllers\Adminhtml\CreateAdminControllerController.php
app\code\local\JR\CreateAdminController\Helper\Data.php
app\code\local\JR\CreateAdminController\Block\Adminhtml\createadmincontroller.php
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\createadmincontroller.xml
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\createadmincontroller\createadmincontroller.phtml
```

Code

Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JR_CreateAdminController>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
        </JR_CreateAdminController>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Model</class>
            </createadmincontroller>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Helper</class>
            </createadmincontroller>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <createadmincontroller>
                <class>JR_CreateAdminController_Block</class>
            </createadmincontroller>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <createadmincontroller before="Mage_Adminhtml">JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</createadmincontroller>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <createadmincontroller>
                    <file>createadmincontroller.xml</file>
                </createadmincontroller>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Adminhtml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <createadmincontroller translate="title" module="createadmincontroller">
            <title>CreateAdminController</title>
            <sort_order>95</sort_order>
            <children>
                <createadmincontroller translate="title" module="createadmincontroller">
                    <title>CreateAdminController</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/createadmincontroller/index</action>
                </createadmincontroller>
            </children>
        </createadmincontroller>
    </menu>
    <!-- The <acl> section is for access control. Here we define the pieces where access can be controlled within a role. -->
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <createadmincontroller>
                        <title>Training Menu Item</title>
                        <children>
                            <createadmincontroller translate="title" module="createadmincontroller">
                                <title>Training Menu Item</title>
                            </createadmincontroller>
                        </children>
                    </createadmincontroller>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

CreateAdminControllerController :

```
<?php

class JR_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CreateAdminControllerController
        extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('createadmincontroller/adminhtml_createadmincontroller');
        Mage::register('myname', 'Ashish Ranade');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Helper :

```
<?php
class JR_CreateAdminController_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Block :

```
<?php

class JR_CreateAdminController_Block_Adminhtml_CreateAdminController 
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function getMyName()
    {
        $name = Mage::registry('myname');
        return ( $name ) ? $name : 'Name not found';
    }

}
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_createadmincontroller_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="createadmincontroller/adminhtml_createadmincontroller" name="createadmincontroller" template="createadmincontroller/createadmincontroller.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_createadmincontroller_index>
</layout>
```

Template :

```
<?php
echo $this->getMyName();
```

This is working module of your scenario, your problem occurs because you had use the keyword in your module name 'Controller' this may cause confusion some time.

Have a happy coding :)

Comment: <blocks> tag is missing from config.xml

Comment: how must i call it in CustomController.php?